# I need to rewrite function inside JSX

Tags: reactjs

I don't know how to exactly phrase my question on google, so that's why I say it here.

I have this piece of code : `<span>{todo.status === "completed" ? <del>{text}</del> : text}</span>`

and I want to rewrite it to be like `<span>{checkHandler}</>`, but it doesn't work and I don't know why.

Why is the shorthand function working, but if I use checkHandler function, then it throws error?

(I am using function component)

```
import React from "react";

const Todo = ({text,setTodos,todos,todo}) =>{

    const deleteHandler = (e) =>{
        setTodos(todos.filter(item => item.id !== todo.id));
    }

    const completeHandler = (e) =>{
        setTodos(todos.map(item => {
            if(item.id === todo.id){
                return{
                    ...item, 
                    status: "completed"
                }
            }
            return item;
        }))
    }
const checkHandler = e => {
  if (todo.status === 'completed') {
    return <del>{text}</del>;
  } else {
    return { text };
  }
};

// ...

return (
  <div className="todo-item">
    <span>{todo.status === 'completed' ? <del>{text}</del> : text}</span>
    <div className="todo-item--completion">
      <button onClick={completeHandler} className="button complete">
        <i className="fas fa-check"></i>
      </button>
      <button onClick={deleteHandler} className="button delete">
        <i className="fas fa-times"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
);
}
```

Comment: Try removing the const for checkhandler and also call it using this keyword. {this.checkhandler}. You also need to pass appropriate parameters to checkhandler.

Comment: Technically you passed into `{}` a callback definition instead of calling it. You can make it work as `{checkHandler()}` instead of `{checkHandler}`.

Comment: I am using function component, so I am not inside class ,Prashanth M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a proper argument to the function and also call it inside jsx:

```
const checkHandler = todo => {
  if (todo.status === 'completed') {
    return <del>{text}</del>;
  } else {
    return text;
  }
};

//...
 <span>{checkHandler(todo)}</span>
```

Comment: Since it's an arrow function, you don't necessarily need to pass in the `todo`, depending on the context, though that is certainly the most explicit way to do it.

Comment: Arrow function doesnt have to do anything with it. But yes, if todo is a prop or saved to the state, it doesn't need to be passed to this function.

Comment: Why do I have to pass todo into the function, when it is globaly available? I think there isn't problem with the argument.

Comment: It's not clear from your code sample whether it's globally available or not. If it is, you can just call the handler without the arg - `{checkHandler()}`

Comment: Sorry, that was my bad. Now I have included the entire component.

Comment: Your code works, I had a mistake somewhere. But I cant still do what I wanted. I wanted to change a color of the element, when the function is true. But this " todo.style.color ="white" " doesn't work . It says Cannot set property 'color' of undefined , when I put it after the if statement, but when I put it inside the return then it says "unreachable code".

Comment: Make sure todo has a `style` property, also you can use conditional chaining to avoid this error - `" todo?.style?.color ="white"`.

Comment: Could you please show me any example? I don't understand it.